# How do I return a new array of all the inputs as strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, concatenation

#### instructions

> Write a function called combiningThings. This function should:
>
> create and return a new array of all inputs as strings
> each of the new strings should start with "[index] is [data]"
>
> For example:

```
combiningThings([1, 2, 3]) // returns ["0 is 1", "1 is 2", "2 is 3"]
combiningThings(['My', 1, 'number']) // returns ["0 is My", "1 is 1", "2 is number"]
```

#### this is what I have so far but I think I'm making the array into a string rather than making a new array of strings:

```
var indexToString = function(arrayTwo) {
  var combine = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayTwo.length; i++) {
    combine += arrayTwo.indexOf(i++) + " is " + arrayTwo[i++];
  }
  return combine;
};
```

Comment: You should use the index of your array. And you can use [`array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Your for loop will allow to sequentially access your array elements.

Comment: Then don't combine it into a string but combine it into an array instead by defining combined as an empty `array()` and then `push()` the new elements into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works with map:

```js
function combiningThings(arr) {
  return arr.map((v, index) => index + ' is ' + v);
}
console.log(combiningThings([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(combiningThings(['My', 1, 'number']));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function combiningThings(array) {
  return array.map((el, index) => {
    return index + ' is ' + el;
  });
}

combiningThings(['My', 1, 'number']); 

// This will give --> [ '0 is My', '1 is 1', '2 is number' ]
```